# Excel: Getting #NUM on calc

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

Why am I getting `#NUM` error in Excel when trying to input:

```
=((171757/-201011)^(1/4))-1
```

It works fine on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28171757%2F-201011%29%5E%281%2F4%29%29-1)..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use imaginary number functions for your equation. Excel expects real numbers for its operations; so it returns `#NUM` when an imaginary number is created and you didn't specify an imaginary number function.

Comment: Run it all the way home.  Explain how to accomplish that.

Comment: @fixer1234 I don't have Excel at home, so I don't know what the functions are. Maybe you could post them and I'll remove my post.

Answer (score 1):

The *fourth root* of a negative number will be a **complex** (real + imaginary) number in the form: `a+bi` that your Excel formula is unable to manage.

You have to rewrite your formula to:

```
=IMSUB(IMSQRT(COMPLEX(0,SQRT((171757/201011)))),1)
```

That will give you the result:

```
-0,3201569+0,67984i
```

The same as Wolphram Alpha